# Getting results only for today's date

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get some of the entries from my db which has dates of only today, here is my working code which gets all of the data;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

 // check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


 // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
    $product["description"] = $row["description"];
    $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

As well as allowing the user to pick a date and display only the data that was created at that date.

The field is;

name     created_at

type     timestamp
null     No
default  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Mysql query you can use DATE() to strip the time of day off of your timestamp like so:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATE(created_at) = '<date>';
```

i.e. this could be implemented as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATE(created_at) = '".date("Y\-m\-d")."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or if you have $inputdate set to be the user specified date.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATE(created_at) = '".$inputdate->format("Y\-m\-d\")."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: so I should change the created_at's type to date() rather than timestamp?

Comment: You could do that if you don't need the time-of-day information for anything else. Btw: Notice that DATE() is a function, while there is also a type called DATE. Mysql is confusing like that.